# Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory and correspondence between fields and subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> Let $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$.
>
> (a) Given a basis for $L/\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> (b) List the elements of $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ and show that $|Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})| = [L/\mathbb{Q}]$. Which known group is isomorphic to $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$?
>
> (c) For each of the following fields $K_{i}$, determine the subgroup $H_{i}$ of $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ corresponding to $K_{i}$ by the Galois correspondence:
> $$K_{1} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10}),\quad K_{2} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{15}),\quad K_{3} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5}),\quad K_{4} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{30}).$$

I already showed the items (a) and (b). If I'm correct, in the item (b), the elements of $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ are the automorphisms that permutes $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}$ and their inverse. But, I don't know how to use it for find the subgroups correspondents. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Take $K_1=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$ for example.  That has degree 2 over $\Bbb{Q}$, so it must be fixed by a subgroup of order 4.  Now obviously the automorphism that sends $\sqrt{3}$ to $-\sqrt{3}$ and fixes $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{5}$ fixes $K_1$.  Also the automorphism which sends $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{5}$ to $-\sqrt{5}$ fixes $K_1$.  The product of those 2 automorphisms plus the identity constitutes the needed subgroup of ordr 4.  $K_2$ has degree $4$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, so there should be a subgroup of order 2 which fixes $K_2$.  Which one?

Comment: @sharding4, about $K_{1}$. For the second automorphism, I can define $\sqrt{3}$ to $-\sqrt{3}$? And, The subgroups would be $\lbrace id, \tau, \sigma, \tau\sigma \rbrace$ where $\tau, \sigma$ are the automorphism that you define, respectively? This groups is ciclic, right?

Comment: Not cyclic.  $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})$ is elementary ableian, i.e. a product of cyclic groups of order 2, and so are all its subgroups.  You need 3 generators for $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})$.  Say $\rho, \sigma, \tau$ with $\rho: \sqrt{2} \mapsto -\sqrt{2}, \sigma: \sqrt{3} \mapsto -\sqrt{3}, \tau: \sqrt{5} \mapsto -\sqrt{5}$  Using that notation $K_1$ is fixed by $\{id, \sigma, \rho \tau, \rho \sigma \tau \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, consider $K_2$. An element
of the Galois group fixes $K_2$ pointwise iff it
fixes $\alpha=\sqrt 6+\sqrt{15}$. The images of $\alpha$ under the
Galois group are the four numbers $\pm\sqrt6\pm\sqrt{15}$. So the subgroup
fixing $\alpha$ has order $8/4=2$, and consists of the identity and one
more element $\sigma$. Bearing in mind that for each of the square roots
$\sqrt2$, $\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt5$, $\sigma$ either fixes it or negates it,
the $\sigma$ in question must have $\sqrt2\mapsto-\sqrt2$,
$\sqrt3\mapsto-\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt5\mapsto-\sqrt5$.